# Push Messages Listener in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I implemented Push Notifications in Blackberry.It works fine.But when i sends message from the server. It shows if the application is running but i need to show the message as Pop Dialog if the application is also not in running.How can do this in Blackberry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit this url

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Pushing-global-screen-message-from-a-background-uiapplication/td-p/439199

it contains code and explaination about runnning the thread in background to listen and it shows pop message (similarly 
try for the push notification and to shows pop message when notification arrives) and for push notification use alternate entry point.

For alternate point visit here

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Set-up-an-alternate-entry-point-for-an-application/ta-p/444847